How to Open a Configuration Tab or Dialog When Clicking ‘Setup’ During App Installation on a Team
we are developing a custom Microsoft Teams application using the Microsoft Developers Portal. Our use case involves creating a Microsoft Teams bot that, when mentioned in a channel, replies to the user based on the context. Initially, we are hardcoding the responses but plan to integrate APIs to dynamically understand queries and respond accordingly.
When the app is installed, we also need to guide users through a sign-up process for our third-party platform. Also, we requires Azure AD permission consent as part of our integration. Without completing the sign-up and integration, the bot will not reply, as it not find the integration detail from our third party platform database
Currently, we want to open a dialog box that links to an external URL for the third-party platform’s sign-up page after a specific Team has been selected. To do this, we created a configurable tab in the app. The tab opens as expected, but it requires the user to click the “Set up a Tab” button. Our goal is to open the configurable tab or a dialog box with the external URL directly when the user clicks the “Setup” button during installation, without needing the “Set up a Tab” interaction.
We have seen this functionality in other apps, such as the JIRA Cloud app, which opens a dialog box when the “Setup” button is clicked during installation. Can you provide guidance or examples on how to implement this functionality in our custom app?
Thank you for your support!
Below are the screenshots what i wants to do:
Jira App installation 
Jira configurable tab after setup button
Try using configurable tabs
